# I have a list in which each element is a single number in a list. How do I extract the numbers?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am a python beginner and I have a list. It goes like this:

```
my_list=[
     {"first":"1"}, 
     {"second": "2"}, 
     {"third": "1"}, 
     {"four": "5"}, 
     {"five":"5"}, 
     {"six":"9"},
     {"seven":"7"}
    ]
```

I want to extract the single values of this list.
I wrote the following piece of code:

```
values = []

for element in my_list:
    val = list(element.values())
    values.append(val)

print(values)
```

This is my output:

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['1'], ['5'], ['5'], ['9'], ['7']]
```

I want only the value numbers to be in my list. [1,2,1,5,5,9,7]
How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost correct but `list(element.values())` gives you a list, You don't want to append *the list itself* but the only item inside it. So do a subscription:

```py
values.append(val[0])
```

or you can use `.extend()` instead of `.append()`:

```py
values.extend(val)
```

If I were to write this, I would do one of these:

```py
print([list(d.values())[0] for d in my_list])
print([next(iter(d.values())) for d in my_list])
```

Comment: Ah this makes so much sense now. Thank you so much! A month ago I tried this and it worked. Now I brushed up on python and the constructs make so much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The `.values()` return a dict_values object, which is an iterable and since you're converting it to a list, so you can extract the first index in order to get your desired format like this

```
values = []

for element in my_list:
    val = list(element.values())[0]
    values.append(val)

print(values)
```

Comment: I tried this code out now, and it says dict_values are not subscriptable. Can you please guide?

Comment: No, dict.values() is a dict_values object (i.e. a [dict view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)). This will raise `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this,

```
In [1]: list(map(lambda x:list(x.values())[0], my_list))
Out[1]: ['1', '2', '1', '5', '5', '9', '7']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list=[
     {"first":"1"},
     {"second": "2"},
     {"third": "1"},
     {"four": "5"},
     {"five":"5"},
     {"six":"9"},
     {"seven":"7"}
     ]
values = [int(element.popitem()[1]) for element 
in my_list]
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, simply [`pop`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_popitem.asp) the (most recently added) item:

```py
>>> my_list = [
...     {"first": "1"},
...     {"second": "2"},
...     {"third": "1"},
...     {"four": "5"},
...     {"five": "5"},
...     {"six": "9"},
...     {"seven": "7"}
... ]
>>> [int(d.popitem()[1]) for d in my_list]
[1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 9, 7]
```